# Combine functions to later use in map

Tags: python, function, dictionary, map-function

I have a list of items, coming from one object which are of type A, and a library that operates on object of type B.

I would like to convert A to B, and later call B's function in a pythonic way. What I have come up with so far:

```
def convert_A_to_B(A):
    return B(A.something, A.something_else)

def doStuff(a_list):
    converted_to_b = list(map(convert_A_to_B, a_list)
    return list(map(B.function, converted_to_b))
```

I could create a lambda to combine these functions, but I feel like there should be an easier way. Something like:

```
return list(map(combine(convert_A_to_B, B.function)))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `list()` on `map()` for `converted_to_b`? That is entirely redundant here.

Comment: you are right, I need the last conversion though

Comment: What is `combine()`? I was unable to find it in the 2.7, 3.3, 3.5 docs.

Comment: Combine is a function that I'm looking for,  I was unable to find it as well. It takes a list of functions and creates a new one which calls each function passing the result as the parameter to the next

Comment: Please be so kind an add this detail to your post. :)

Comment: `combine = lambda *xs: partial(reduce, lambda v,x: x(v), [*xs])`, now you can write `map (combine (convert_A_to_B, B.function), a_list)`.

Comment: @Filip could you add this as an answer?  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import partial, reduce
combine = lambda *xs: partial (reduce, lambda v,x: x(v), xs)
```

<sup>The function is usable such as `combine (A.foo, A.bar) (x)` with is equivalent to `A.bar(A.foo (x))`.</sup>

<sup>`combine` will accept a variadic number of functions, and return a new function that accepts a single value. This value will then be passed through every previously mentioned function (in chain) until a final result is yield.</sup>

---

#### Sample usage

```
map (combine (convert_A_to_B, B.function), a_list)
```

Comment: there seems to be an error with your code, I received can use starred expression as assignment target

Comment: I've edited your answer to remove the upacking, it works fine without it

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a list comprehension rather than `list(map(...))` here:

```
return [B(A.something, A.something_else).function() for A in a_list]
```

You could do the same with `map()` and a `lambda` but the above is more readable:

```
return list(map(lambda A: B(A.something, A.something_else).function(), a_list))
```

If you want to re-use `converted_to_b` just do so:

```
return [converted_to_b(A).function() for A in a_list]
```

Comment: I still need to put convert_A_to_B somewhere

Comment: this is a minimal example, the actuall function is a bit longer

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: right, then just use it in the list comprehension instead of the `B(...)` expression.